# Dynamically set href in iframe not working in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, iframe, mailto

I have a page (jobs.php) which has all the mobile features like call, sms and email. I am accessing this page as an iframe in the main `index.php` page.
I have made a function such that before making a call or sms or email, it logs the entry into the database.

jobs.php code

Javascript (all variable are defined and working)

```
<img src=\""+imgpath+"email_logo.png\"onclick=\"setMailLog('"+installername+"',"+customerId+",'"+email+"')\" id=\"mimg_"+customerId+"\"/>


function setMailLog(installerName, customerId,email){
        console.log("Email Attempted:");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'functions.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType:'text',
      data: 'elogins='+installerName+'&elogcid='+customerId,
      success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $("#mimg_"+customerId).wrap('<a id="mhrefid_'+customerId+'" target="_blank"></a>');
        $('#mhrefid_'+customerId).attr('href','mailto:'+email);
        window.location.href=$("#mhrefid_"+customerId).attr('href');
      } 

   }); 

    }
```

This is working perfectly fine on all desktop browsers. Its working fine on default browser in Android but breaks on Chrome in Android which is important because these are mobile features and should work on mobile device on every browser.

When I click on the mail icon in Chrome on Android, it says

```
The web page at mailto:email might be temporarily down or it may have removed permanently to a new address

Error 302(net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME): Unknown error
```

The error page shows up only in particular iframe and not on the whole index.php file.

Call and sms functions the same way, just the error changes to `tel:5225` or `sms:5114`

This is all in an iframe, may be that's what causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. I've created a ticket to track it https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=223146

To work around the issue, replace

```
window.location.href=$("#mhrefid_"+customerId).attr('href');
```

with

```
window.top.location.href=$("#mhrefid_"+customerId).attr('href');
```

That changes the location of the top-level page rather than the iframe, which works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks Jaffa..I'll try this solution tonight. You know the problem occurs only on Galaxy, works fine in Chrome on tablet. Strange!!

Comment: Great!! That's working but the only a small problem with it is that it clears out the console. Is there any way I can prevent that from happening?

Comment: Right click the console and select "preserve log upon navigation"